# How do I use a cucumber hook to close multiple firefox windows?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, testing, cucumber

I have a cucumber feature that opens a link in a new window. I handle this in chrome with

```
After do |scenario|

  # Close all web browser tabs and windows
  page.driver.browser.window_handles.each do |handle|
    page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(handle)
    page.execute_script "window.close()"
  end

end
```

This works in Chrome but in firefox I get the error:

```
Window not found. The browser window may have been closed. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError)
```

Please help. I have no idea why this doesn't work in Firefox.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not within that new window do,

```
Driver.close();
```

To close the window